# Create React Context that returns 2 Other Functions Through Context Provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm relatively new to ReactJS and TypeScript and could use some help with creating a react component that allows me to call methods and realize I probably have a lot of mistakes. Below is my code.

```
import { SomeExternalPackage } from "@external";

interface MyServiceProviderProps { 
       isInternal: boolean; 
       isEnabled: boolean;
} 
    
export const MyServiceProvider: React.FC<MyProviderProps> = (serviceProperty: MyServiceProviderProps) => { 
       const reportImpressionAsync = (creative: string) => {
               if (serviceProperty.isEnabled) {
                       SomeExternalPackage?.reportImpressionAsync(creative);
               }
       } 

       const reportActionAsync = (creative: string, action: SomeExternalPackage.Action) => { 
                   if (serviceProperty.isInternal) {
                       SomeExternalPackage?.reportActionAsync(creative, action);
               }
       } 

       const MyServiceContext = React.createContext(''); // TODO: What do I pass in here?
       return ( 
               <MyServiceContext.Provider value={{
                       reportActionAsync: reportActionAsync,
                       reportImpressionAsync: reportImpressionAsync
                       }}>
                   {serviceProperty} // Is this right?
               </MyServiceContext.Provider> 
       );
};
```

This is a rough idea of what I have so far. Ideally from a page component, I could use the .Consumer to supply these 2 functions and inside of a page I could call either function.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to answer your question without understanding more about what you are trying to achieve.

My impression is that Context is not the right solution to your problem and it could be better solved with a custom hook or a high-order-component.

Where will the `isEnabled` and `isInternal` properties come from? Are they things that you need to change or are they coming from some static config?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! 

The problem I am trying to solve is I want a universal way to access these 2 functions from any of the child components wrappers by the context provider.

I imagine the isEnabled and isInternal could be supplied when creating an instance of MyServiceProvider that wraps around page components. So all pages that are wrapped by this provider with these 2 member args have access to these 2 functions/params.

Does that sound okay? Would love to hear your thoughts :)

Comment: Is there a different instance of MyServiceProvider for different pages or is it the same across the app?

Comment: I would be curious to know how that impacts the answer.

I think right now it would be the same across the app but would love to hear the other side too if you could

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I've understood, something like this should work:

```
import React from 'react'

// faking SomeExternalPackage
type Action = unknown

const SomeExternalPackage = {
    reportActionAsync: (creative: string, action: Action) => {},
    reportImpressionAsync: (creative: string) => {}
}

interface MyServiceProviderProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
     isInternal: boolean; 
     isEnabled: boolean;
}

export const MyServiceContext = React.createContext({
    reportActionAsync: (creative: string, action: Action) => {},
    reportImpressionAsync: (creative: string) => {}
})
    
export const MyServiceProvider: React.FC<MyServiceProviderProps> = (props: MyServiceProviderProps) => { 
    const reportImpressionAsync = (creative: string) => {
        if (props.isEnabled) {
            SomeExternalPackage.reportImpressionAsync(creative);
        }
    } 

    const reportActionAsync = (creative: string, action: Action) => { 
        if (props.isInternal) {
            SomeExternalPackage.reportActionAsync(creative, action);
        }
    } 

    return ( 
        <MyServiceContext.Provider value={{
            reportActionAsync: reportActionAsync,
            reportImpressionAsync: reportImpressionAsync
        }}>
        {props.children}
        </MyServiceContext.Provider> 
    );
};
```

You can then take this `MyServiceProvider` component and render it somewhere near the top level of your application (like in your `App` component) so that it wraps all other components and provides these functions.

To use those functions in another component you would do something like this:

```
import { MyServiceContext } from 'path/to/MyServiceContext'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { reportActionAsync, reportImpressionAsync } = React.useContext(MyServiceContext)
}
```

Comment: Thank You!!! This is awesome and really helped me out moving forward